# Making both Site name & Site slogan to be one single link in mini-panels

Tags: navigation, panels

I use the **Mini Panels** module and have created an header with both **Page elements** "Site name" & "Site slogan".

The Site name (H1) is a clickable link that leads to the home page, but the site slogan (H2) is just a text that links nowhere.

Can I make both of them a single link to the homepage (but still keep them different elements with different CSS, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I see three options that I think you could do.

1. Update the content in the theme layer which you can try to check in this page and it's other related pages. https://www.drupal.org/node/1678810
2. Use panel pane hooks to add additional settings for the *Site Slogan* panel pane.
3. Create a custom panel pane

Comment: Please detail more of 2&3, I think I don't have enough data to have final decision of what you mean :|

Comment: I think for 2 and 3, you can base some ways from here https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2014/01/03/how-to-create-a-custom-panels-pane/. Based on my research #2 looks the hardest to implement for me. So I would suggest either create a custom pane or just use the theme preprocess functions available. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey man, sorry to say but the link is broken... I think that num 2 should be the 3 because not all users already learned programming (I've yet to learn)... please detail a bit inside the answer what worked best for you to make them single link (but still H1&H2).